# wrong data returned when scraping specific text from specific table elements

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Thanks to SO and @QHarr, the following code works fine with URLs such as

```
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00FSCBQV2
```

But it doesn't work with a URL such as this -

```
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01N1ZD912/
```

My result is -

```
'R1_NO' :'.zg_hrsr { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: 
none;}\n.zg_hrsr_item { margin: 0 0 0 10px; }\n.zg_hrsr_rank { 
display:inline-block; width: 80px; text-align: right; }'}'
```

it should be returning

```
R1_NO = 42553 
R1_CAT = Baby Care Products
R2_NO = 6452
R2_CAT = Baby Bathing Products (Health & Household)
```

This is due to the ranking data not on the first line. What needs to be done to get the desired results? Also can this script be condensed/more efficient?

I've tried handling it with bs4 select.one, getting text strip, nothing I do works. Please help me!

```
fields = ['Amazon Best Sellers Rank']

            temp_dict = {}

            for field in fields:
                element = soup.select_one('li:contains("' + field + '")')
                if element is None:
                    temp_dict[field] = 'NA'
                else:
                    if field == 'Amazon Best Sellers Rank':
                        item='NA'
                        item = [re.sub('#|\(','', string).strip() for string in soup.select_one('li:contains("' + field + '")').stripped_strings][1].split(' in ')
                        temp_dict[field] = item
                    else:
                        item = [string for string in element.stripped_strings][1]
                        temp_dict[field] = item.replace('(', '').strip()

            ranks = soup.select('.zg_hrsr_rank')
            ladders = soup.select('.zg_hrsr_ladder')

            if ranks:
                cat_nos = [item.text.split('#')[1] for item in ranks]
            else:
                 cat_nos = ['NA']

            if ladders:
                cats = [item.text.split('\xa0')[1] for item in soup.select('.zg_hrsr_ladder')]
            else:
                cats = ['NA']

            rankings = dict(zip(cat_nos, cats))

            map_dict = {'Amazon Best Sellers Rank': ['R1_NO','R1_CAT']}

            final_dict = {}

            final_dict['R2_NO'] = 'NA'
            final_dict['R2_CAT'] = 'NA'
            final_dict['R3_NO'] = 'NA'
            final_dict['R3_CAT'] = 'NA'
            final_dict['R4_NO'] = 'NA'
            final_dict['R4_CAT'] = 'NA'

            for k,v in temp_dict.items():
                if k == 'Amazon Best Sellers Rank' and v!= 'NA':
                    item = dict(zip(map_dict[k],v))
                    final_dict = {**final_dict, **item}
                elif k == 'Amazon Best Sellers Rank' and v == 'NA':
                    item = dict(zip(map_dict[k], [v, v]))
                    final_dict = {**final_dict, **item}
                else:
                    final_dict[map_dict[k]] = v

            for k,v in enumerate(rankings):
                #print(k + 1, v, rankings[v])
                prefix = 'R' + str(k + 2) + '_'
                final_dict[prefix + 'NO'] = v
                final_dict[prefix + 'CAT'] = rankings[v]
```

I expect it to handle and return values for both URLs posted in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So due to difference in html layout the stripped strings leads to the inline css being returned. You could try shortening and using regex. One could tighten up the regex but I will wait and see if you find fail cases first.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

links = ['https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00FSCBQV2?th=1','https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01N1ZD912/','https://www.amazon.com/Professional-Dental-Guard-Remoldable-Customizable/dp/B07L4YHBQ4', 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0040ODFK4/?tag=stackoverfl08-20']
map_dict = {'Product Dimensions': 'dimensions', 'Shipping Weight': 'weight', 'Item model number': 'Item_No', 'Amazon Best Sellers Rank': ['R1_NO','R1_CAT']}

# This handles when a ranking is from 1 to x,xxx,xxx
p = re.compile(r'#([0-9][0-9,]*)+[\n\s]+in[\n\s]+([A-Za-z&\s]+)')

with requests.Session() as s:
    for link in links:
        r = s.get(link, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla\5.0'})
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        fields = ['Product Dimensions', 'Shipping Weight', 'Item model number', 'Amazon Best Sellers Rank']
        final_dict = {}

        for field in fields:
            element = soup.select_one('li:contains("' + field + '")')
            if element is None:
                if field == 'Amazon Best Sellers Rank':
                    item = dict(zip(map_dict[field], ['N/A','N/A']))
                    final_dict = {**final_dict, **item}
                else:
                    final_dict[map_dict[field]] = 'N/A'
            else:
                if field == 'Amazon Best Sellers Rank':      
                    text = element.text
                    i = 1
                    for x,y in p.findall(text):
                        prefix = 'R' + str(i) + '_'
                        final_dict[prefix + 'NO'] = x  
                        final_dict[prefix + 'CAT'] = y.strip()
                        i+=1
                else:
                    item = [string for string in element.stripped_strings][1]
                    final_dict[map_dict[field]] = item.replace('(', '').strip()
        print(final_dict)
```

Comment: It works for all except for     https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07L4YHBQ4    its only returning the R1s and not R2 or R3. I think it has to do with     p = re.compile(r'#(\d+,?\d+)     bc I played around with it and got it to show R2 and R3 but it failed to show R1.

Comment: I'll have a look

Comment: I solved this by changing    (\d+,?\d+)    to    (\d{0,20},?\d+) I believe its due to having a rank of '1' and having regex call the zero line. If you know of a better way please alter your answer. I edited it but by all means do so if needed.

Comment: if you are happy then I am happy.... until the next link that breaks it ;-)

Comment: Does your altered regex work for each link originally used?

Comment: Yes - I used all 4 sites from your answer and all returned 100%. Ill be posting a new Q related to this today so keep your eye out for it : )  Thanks for all your input its  phenomenal.

Comment: Yey! Will do. You can also drop a link to it here as then I will know it is up. I prefer this script to the prior answer. More succinct and logic clearer IMO.

Comment: Can you check the regex? I am not getting R2 =1 , R3 = 1 for  https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07L4YHBQ4 . It was working until I added the second    '?\d+' to handle ranks of x,xxx,xxx . There seems to be an issue with single digit handling aka ' 1 '

Comment: less secure but maybe #([0-9,])+[\n\s]+in[\n\s]+([A-Za-z&\s]+)  . I can't remember what my regex was before so would need to look and test but am busy at mo.The above allows for a character set. You could adjust to specify must start with number #[0-9][0-9,]* etc...

Comment: p = re.compile(r'#([0-9][0-9,]*)+[\n\s]+in[\n\s]+([A-Za-z&\s]+)')  has solved all issues. I get 1 through x,xxx,xxx  when tested. That was fun!

Comment: Here is the final Q!  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57185019/how-to-scrape-an-element-in-different-locations-in-one-script

Comment: Doesn't look like you need two entire scripts. You can use the same code once but add a test that determines what value to assign to p. Is _fields_ different ? I think just shortened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196939/discussion-between-workin-4weekend-and-qharr).