# How to condense script when scraping different locations for one element

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have 2 working scripts that do their job. I want to combine them for efficiency and reduce redundancy. I am using Python 3.7, Beautifulsoup 4.7.1, re, and requests.

script 1 searches 'li' and works with these test URLs
     [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00FSCBQV2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FSCBQV2)
     [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07L4YHBQ4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L4YHBQ4)
     [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01N1ZD912](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N1ZD912)
     [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0040ODFK4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0040ODFK4)

script 2 searches 'tr' and works with these test URLs
     [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00Q2XLI0U](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00Q2XLI0U)
     [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00CYVCWXG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CYVCWXG)

I tried using (shorthand)
    Try: 
      script1
    Else:
       Try: 
         script2
       else:
          pass

But it gets hairy and fails. I would like it in the try , except, pass format.

```
#Script 1 
map_dict = {'Amazon Best Sellers Rank': ['R1_NO','R1_CAT']}
p = re.compile(r'#([0-9][0-9,]*)+[\n\s]+in[\n\s]+([A-Za-z&\s]+)')
fields = ['Amazon Best Sellers Rank']
final_dict = {}
#to handle null when writing to oracle later
final_dict['R1_NO'] = 'NA'
final_dict['R1_CAT'] = 'NA'
final_dict['R2_NO'] = 'NA'
final_dict['R2_CAT'] = 'NA'
final_dict['R3_NO'] = 'NA'
final_dict['R3_CAT'] = 'NA'
final_dict['R4_NO'] = 'NA'
final_dict['R4_CAT'] = 'NA'

for field in fields:
    element = soup.select_one('li:contains("' + field + '")')
    if element is None:
         item = dict(zip(map_dict[field], ['NA','NA']))
         final_dict = {**final_dict, **item}
    else:
        text = element.text
        i = 1
        for x,y in p.findall(text):
        prefix = 'R' + str(i) + '_'
        final_dict[prefix + 'NO'] = x
        final_dict[prefix + 'CAT'] = y.strip()
        i+=1

#Script 2 
map_dict = {'Best Sellers Rank': ['R1_NO','R1_CAT']}
p = re.compile(r'#([0-9][0-9,]*)+[\n\s]+in[\n\s]+([A-Za-z&\s]+)')
fields = ['Best Sellers Rank']
final_dict = {}
#to handle null when writing to oracle later
final_dict['R1_NO'] = 'NA'
final_dict['R1_CAT'] = 'NA'
final_dict['R2_NO'] = 'NA'
final_dict['R2_CAT'] = 'NA'
final_dict['R3_NO'] = 'NA'
final_dict['R3_CAT'] = 'NA'
final_dict['R4_NO'] = 'NA'
final_dict['R4_CAT'] = 'NA'

for field in fields:
    element = soup.select_one('tr:contains("' + field + '")')
    if element is None:
         item = dict(zip(map_dict[field], ['NA','NA']))
         final_dict = {**final_dict, **item}
    else:
        text = element.text
        i = 1
        for x,y in p.findall(text):
        prefix = 'R' + str(i) + '_'
        final_dict[prefix + 'NO'] = x
        final_dict[prefix + 'CAT'] = y.strip()
        i+=1
```

I expect to have a combined DRY script that works on all provided URLs. script would look in 'li' then if its not there it looks in "tr' and if its not there, the values are assigned 'NA'. Again, this works separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine the two into one (as most is using same code). Simply make the field names the same across both. `:contains` will still match on shortened field name of `Best Sellers Rank`, and then use css Or syntax to handle `tr` versus `li`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

links = ['https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00FSCBQV2','https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00Q2XLI0U']
map_dict = {'Product Dimensions': 'dimensions', 'Shipping Weight': 'weight', 'Item model number': 'Item_No', 'Best Sellers Rank': ['R1_NO','R1_CAT']}

p = re.compile(r'#([0-9][0-9,]*)+[\n\s]+in[\n\s]+([A-Za-z&\s]+)')

with requests.Session() as s:
    for link in links:
        r = s.get(link, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla\5.0'})
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        fields = ['Product Dimensions', 'Shipping Weight', 'Item model number', 'Best Sellers Rank']
        final_dict = {}

        for field in fields:
            element = soup.select_one('li:contains("' + field + '"), tr:contains("' + field + '")')
            if element is None:
                if field == 'Best Sellers Rank':
                    item = dict(zip(map_dict[field], ['N/A','N/A']))
                    final_dict = {**final_dict, **item}
                else:
                    final_dict[map_dict[field]] = 'N/A'
            else:
                if field == 'Best Sellers Rank':      
                    text = element.text
                    i = 1
                    for x,y in p.findall(text):
                        prefix = 'R' + str(i) + '_'
                        final_dict[prefix + 'NO'] = x  
                        final_dict[prefix + 'CAT'] = y.strip()
                        i+=1
                else:
                    item = [string for string in element.stripped_strings][1]
                    final_dict[map_dict[field]] = item.replace('(', '').strip()
        print(final_dict)
```

Comment: Think you can help? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57227194/building-a-proxy-rotator-with-specific-url-and-script