# Building a proxy rotator with specific URL and script

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, proxy, rotation

I am struggling to build a proxy rotator with existing code structured for a different url.

The URLs I want are provided in the code example below. I am trying to have the provided script call the desired URLs and get **ALL** the 'IP:PORT' (current script limits to ten) when proxy type is "HTTPS". 

It can be done in xpath or bs4. I am familair with bs4 more though.

I understand the logic but I am failing on how to structure this. 
To start, I've tried stripping strings and trying to call specific td elements but its not working.

```
#URLs I want 
url_list = ['http://spys.one/free-proxy-list/US/','http://spys.one/free-proxy-list/US/1/']

#code I have 
 from lxml.html import fromstring
 import requests
 from itertools import cycle
 import traceback

 def get_proxies():
 url = 'https://free-proxy-list.net/'
 response = requests.get(url)
 parser = fromstring(response.text)
 proxies = set()
 for i in parser.xpath('//tbody/tr')[:10]:
     if i.xpath('.//td[7][contains(text(),"yes")]'):
        proxy = ":".join([i.xpath('.//td[1]/text()')[0], i.xpath('.//td[2]/text()')[0]])
        proxies.add(proxy)
return proxies

proxies = get_proxies()
proxy_pool = cycle(proxies)
proxy = next(proxy_pool)
response = requests.get(url,proxies={"http": proxy, "https": proxy})
```

I hope to learn how the code provided is structured for the 2 desired URLs, return all IP:PORT numbers when proxy type is HTTPS

Comment: You can get the IP from `http://spys.one/free-proxy-list/US/` and `http://spys.one/free-proxy-list/US/1/` sites using requests module but you can't get `PORT` as they generate dynamically.

Comment: This isn't what we mean when we talk about proxy rotators. A proxy rotator is a proxy that forwards to a random upstream proxy.

Comment: my apologies im trying to make a list of "Proxy address:port" from the 2 URLs to put in a function when proxy type = https. This data is scrapable as text in the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to issue port specific POST requests in a loop. You could amend to add to one final list. The endpoint is already https specific.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_proxies(number, port, p):
    r = requests.post('http://spys.one/en/https-ssl-proxy/', data = {'xpp': 5, 'xf4': number})
    proxies = [':'.join([str(i),port]) for i in p.findall(r.text)]
    return proxies

ports = ['3128', '8080', '80']
p = re.compile(r'spy14>(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})<script')
proxies = []

for number, port in enumerate(ports,1):
    proxies+=get_proxies(number, port, p)

print(proxies)
```

---

**Example results:**

[image]

---

**For country specific:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_proxies(number, port, p, country):
    r = requests.post('http://spys.one/en/https-ssl-proxy/',  data = {'xpp': 5, 'xf4': number})
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    proxies = [':'.join([p.findall(i.text)[0], port]) for i in soup.select('table table tr:has(.spy14:contains("' + country + '")) td:has(script) .spy14')]
    return proxies

ports = ['3128', '8080', '80']
p = re.compile(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})document')
proxies = []

for number, port in enumerate(ports,1):
    proxies+=get_proxies(number, port, p, 'United States')

print(proxies)
```

---

For the one you said is already written I will refer to my original answer of:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

def get_proxies(): 
    r = requests.get('https://free-proxy-list.net/')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    proxies = {tr.td.text + ':' + tr.td.next_sibling.text for tr in soup.select('tr:has(.hx:contains(yes))')} 
    return proxies 

get_proxies()
```

Comment: Hi the code is already written for that url, I’m trying to structure for url_list = ['http://spys.one/free-proxy-list/US/','http://spys.one/free-proxy-list/US/1/']

Comment: creative, how do u handle new ports, i see on site there are https with other ports. couldnt we capture "proxyaddress:port" when proxy type = https with 'td'[1] text contains "S" ?somehow?

Comment: The POST only relates to the listed dropdown options for ports. Otherwise, it is quite a difficult javascript algorithm will actually encodes/decodes the port on the page.

Comment: I have added the xpp parameter which allows up to 500 servers in results. The list for US goes up to 81 proxies then for the three specified ports.

Comment: How can this handle 2 urls and Would we need country specified if the desired 2 urls have US only in the url ;  url_list = ['http://spys.one/free-proxy-list/US/','http://spys.one/free-proxy-list/US/1/']

Comment: The code would need amending to pick up the https. So it was 1 way of the other. As we only care about https I chose to go with the https and then filter on country in one scripts and provide all countries in the other script

Comment: Those two urls are only subsets of the full set which my code works with I think.

Comment: I thought port could be captured in td[1] class=‘spy1’. Thus grabbing all ports. But I might be approaching my logic incorrectly.

Comment: I mean intersection not subset. The port is rendered by the script tag within the td so needs browser to appear as on page. The JavaScript algorithm used for this is quite difficult to follow but I may look at it properly tomorrow to see if can be reverse engineered.  Not a trivial task. The potential for large number of ports  and being banned means probing ports, to complete the missing items, with something like telnet is probably not a good idea.

Comment: dont go through all that trouble. You are brilliant. You provided a better approach than my limiting 2 sites.You current approach is smart and most important it not just solves, but it teaches. I am able to learn from your answer. thank you x100

Comment: Hi Friend, I am still using this today but now I am not getting any proxies. I am using the one you  built "country specfic" . Any idea why? Thanks  @QHarr